# Which is better - using extern or declaring a struct array in a header file and defining it in .c in C

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-optimization

Define the array struct in a header file `ex.h`

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct example_t{
    const char *pStr;
    uint32_t size;
} example_t;

struct example_t array_struct[2];
```

Then initialize the array struct in a .c file `ex1.c`

```
#include "ex.h"

struct example_t array_struct[2] = {{"hello", 5}, {"world", 5}};

void ex1()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
       printf("%s\n", array_struct[i].pStr);
       printf("%u\n", array_struct[i].size);
   } 
}
```

Also use the initialized struct array in another .c file
`ex2.c`

```
#include "ex.h"

void ex2()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
       printf("%s\n", array_struct[i].pStr);
       printf("%u\n", array_struct[i].size);
   } 
}
```

Is this a good practice or it is best to use `extern` in `ex2.c` and define it in `ex1.c`?

Comment: Putting the array declaration in the header only makes sense if all users of the struct should be that same 2-element array.

Comment: @Barmar if it has `external linkage` the only one object having this name can exist in the whole project. How can you have different ones with external linkage sharing the same name? I do not understand your comment

Comment: @0___________ My point is that some applications may need an external array with 10 elements.  Defining the struct type and defining the array should be independent.

Comment: @Barmar struct **declaratio** and array **definition** are separate. DEclaration of the extern object is placed in the .h file. Size should be macrodefinition set somewhere in the settings.h (or similar) file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
struct example_t array_struct[2];
```

Is not declaring an array, but is *defining* an array.  Using this will result in a compilation error for multiple definitions when you link your .c files into an executable.

To declare it, you need to add `extern`:

```
extern struct example_t array_struct[2];
```

Comment: I didn't encounter any compilation error actually.

Comment: @pavikirthi Some compilers will perform "folding" of globals, where multiple definitions without an initializer will be considered a single object, however not all do that.

Comment: But, is it a good practice to define an array struct as an ```extern struct example_t array_struct[2];``` in a header file? And, initialize it in a .c file and also use it another .c files as well?

Comment: That's not defining, that's declaring, and it's exactly what you should do in a header.  Had you compiled your with some other compiler you would have gotten an error.

Comment: @pavikirthi: yes, it is good practice, and furthermore you must include the header file with the declaration in the source file that actually defines the object so the compiler can check that the declaration and definitions are consistent.

Comment: @pavikirthi: GCC's default used to be `-fcommon` and would silently ignore multiple identical definitions in C mode.  That's no longer the case.  It changed somewhere between GCC6 and GCC11 or so, IIRC.  Maybe you're using an older GCC, or some other compiler that handles this like C++, not erroring in some places where C compilers are allowed to error.

Answer (score 2):

The header file should only contain declarations: the array must be declared with the `extern` keyword, if this keyword is absent, you have a definition, not a declaration:

**ex.h**:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct example_t {
    const char *pStr;
    uint32_t size;
} example_t;

extern struct example_t array_struct[2];
```

It is good practice to include the header file with the declaration in the source file that actually defines the object so the compiler can check that the declaration and definitions are consistent.  In your case, you need the structure definition, but in other cases without such a constaint, it is still safer to include the header file with the object declaration.